# How to execute OpenSSL command in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, openssl, inputstream

I need to run a OpenSSL command programatically in android, but it throws the following error:

"Cannot run program "openssl": error=2, No such file or directory"

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   executeSH("openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out prime-private-key.pem",true);

}
  private String executeSH(String command, boolean waitFor) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process process = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String line, output = "";
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                output += line;
                File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
                File newDir = new File(path + "/" + "a.txt");
                if (!newDir.exists()) {
                    newDir.mkdir();
                }
                FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, "a.txt"));
                writer.write(output.getBytes());
                writer.close();
                Log.e("TAG", "Wrote to file: " + "a.txt");
            }
                if (waitFor) {
                    process.waitFor();
                }
                return output;
            }
        finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) bufferedReader.close();
            if (inputStreamReader != null) inputStreamReader.close();
            if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
            if (process != null) process.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Maybe someone can help me solve this question.

Comment: The external storage directory `/sdcard` alias `/storage/emulated/0` is AFAIK mounted with no-execute restriction. So saving openssl binary there and trying to execute will not work. The app-private dir should also be restricted because the write xor execute restriction. So you could test `/data/local` or `/data/local/tmp`.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error, even after trying this path.